# How are some wand combinations more powerful than others?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore

We know that Holly and Phoenix Tail Feather is a more powerful combination than when paired with Unicorn Hair or Dragon Heartstring.

> Holly is one of those woods that varies most dramatically in performance depending on the wand core, and it is a notoriously difficult wood to team with phoenix feather, as the wood's volatility conflicts strangely with the phoenix's detachment. In the unusual event of such a pairing finding its ideal match, however, nothing and nobody should stand in their way.

https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/wand-woods

Why is this so? Are some wand wood more "reactive" to some core and produce stronger magic?

Comment: The actual question imo is why wouldn't it be. This is true for almost anything: Different wood = different properties. So some materials channel magic better just like some woods are better for building certain instruments or furniture or simply burning it and sometimes different materials are not straight up better but only different.

Comment: Can you provide a citation for the quote in your question, please?

Comment: *"nothing and nobody should stand in their way"* really?  I am not convinced. Sounds like a bad salesman line, Mr. O

Answer (score 11):

### It's a secret

Sorry if this seems like a non answer, but while we know something about combinations of wood, core, length, flexibility and personality; the reality is that the how is a guarded family secret.

> His methods of locating wand woods and core substances marrying them together and matching them to ideal owners are all jealously guarded secrets that were coveted by rival wandmakers.
>
> *Mr. Ollivander on Pottermore by JK Rowling*